# Find product of 5 consecutive integer in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to calculate the product of 5 consecutive integer, but the result the completely wrong. I think my logic is correct, but why it shows me an unreal number: `344362200`

The sequence number is from 1 to 10, code is below (just for testing only):

```
void problem8()
{
    char *input = "123456789";
    char c;
    int step = 5, i = 0, prod = 0, temp = 1;
    for (; i < step; i++)
    {
        temp *= *(input + i);
        printf("%d\n", temp);
    }
}
```

The output is really weird! At the first loop, the result is 42 @@ while it should be 1, and 1 only. I checked individual result from *(input + 0) or 1 2 4 etc., it's correct. But the product is wrong.

Comment: Well there you go, the answer is 42. Shouldn't it be 49 though? It is if I compile your code.

Comment: Try `input[i] - '0'` instead of `*(input + i)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the codes for the digits (48 for `'0'`, 49 for `'1'`, etc), and the numbers 1, 2, etc.  You should be getting 49 on the first iteration; indeed, I get:

```
49
2450
124950
6497400
344362200
```

If you want the first 5 factorials, you'll need to use `temp *= input[i] - '0';` (where `input[i]` is neater than `*(input + i)`, IMNSHO).

The codes I gave are valid for code sets such as ISO 8859-1, and also UTF-8, and many other related code sets.  They're not valid for EBCDIC, though.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are converting a `char` to an int, and not taking into account the ASCII offsets in the ASCII table. Integers start at hex `0x30` for ASCII.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int multiplyFiveSingleDigitNumbersInAString (const char* input, size_t inputLength);

int main(void) {
   int tmp = 0;
   const char* buf = "12345"; /* Create null-terminated string */
   tmp = multiplyFiveSingleDigitNumbersInAString(buf, strlen(buf));
   printf("Result of calculation for string %s is %d\n", buf, tmp);
   return 0;
}

int multiplyFiveSingleDigitNumbersInAString (const char* input, size_t inputLength) {
   if (inputLength != 5) {
      printf("Wrong string length (%d), should be %d\n", (int)inputLength, 5);
      return 0;
   }
   int i;
   int multiSum = 1;
   for (i=0; i<inputLength; i++) {
      multiSum *= (int)input[i] - 0x30;
   }
   return multiSum;
}
```

**References**

1. *ASCII Table*, Accessed 2014-04-08, [`<http://www.asciitable.com/>`](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: +1 but... I wonder about the design decision to embody the length in the function name, especially given the sample data which uses a string of length 9 with no ill effect.  A function `multiplySingleDigitNumbersInAString(const char *input, size_t len)` makes sense; so does `multiplySingleDigitNumbersInAString(const char *input)` to take the whole string.  You should use `'0'` in place of 0x30; then your code will work on an EBCDIC machine too.  If you're checking for length, you should probably check that the 'digits' actually are digits: `if (!isdigit((unsigned char)input[i])) return 0;`.

Comment: Also, errors should be printed to standard error, not standard output.  And it is debatable whether the function should print at all; it would be better if it returned an unambiguous error (-1 can't be legitimate; 0 can be if one of the digits is zero) in silence. The calling code can then report the problem.

Comment: The OP never mentioned strings ... the question refers to "5 consecutive integer". It's weird that people are preserving the *one wrong thing* in the code and changing the rest of it, rather than the other way around. See my answer for a far more sensible approach.

Comment: @JimBalter I made a point to address some of the key flaws. I could have re-written it to accept an array of integers instead, etc, but I'm hesitant to do a total bug-proof solution, and doing *all* of the work for OP.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the other answers approach this backwards. Simply don't use chars when you want ints. Just change

```
char *input = "123456789";
```

to

```
int input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

and your code will work.

P.S. Here's a solution to the actual problem:

```
char digits[] = "731...";

int main(void)
{
    int max = 0;

    for (int len = sizeof digits - 1, i = 0; i < len - 4; i++)
    {
        int prod = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            prod *= digits[i + j] - '0';
        if (max < prod) max = prod;
    }
    printf("%d\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if the input is 1000 long, how will u put it into an array of int?? well you can see it in this [link] (http://projecteuler.net/problem=8)

Comment: @TrungBún If you want an answer to a specific question, ask **that** question, don't add it on as a comment. Given your *new* question, putting the digits in a string is a little easier, and then you subtract `'0'` as you've been told, but it's also trivial to turn that into an int array with a few keystrokes in emacs or vi, or with a script in Perl or something similar.

Comment: I'm appreciate your help! But I prefer to do it in my way of thinking! If I fail then maybe I will create a new post or comment somewhere else to seek help. And you see? My code is working! If I don't do it in my way, then how I know to convert from a char to an int just by: char - '0' ? How can I know that the number 49 from my output is a dec of ASCII character? This would help me in the future. But thank you anyway!! :)